# UIDocument opening is never finished

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, icloud, uidocument

I have an iOS 5.1 app, and I'm trying to optimize it for iOS 6. The problem is that `openWithCompletionHandler:` is never finished. As I see, second device can't download this file. But device-owner works with file fine.

My app uses 2 file types: the first is only text data, and the second is text with picture data. Everything is completely cool with text files. I suppose the problem is in file size, but delay (I tried 40 seconds) doesn't help for me.

I try to use `dataWithContentsOfFile:` instead of UIDocument and the result is

> Data: (null) WithError: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)"

I'm using the following code to open the document

```
[currentFile openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
   NSLog(@"File Opened"); // <<--- Not processed, never reached
}];
```

I added the following right before opening, but it has no effect:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
```